# How to configure category-list (TYPO3 news extension) via TypoScript

Tags: typo3, typoscript, tx-news, typo3-10.x

I have a blog page on one of the websites which is done using TypoScript to avoid having a list and detail page.

I have called the TypoScript as an object: `lib.newslist`.

```html
plugin.tx_news.settings.list.paginate.itemsPerPage = 6
lib.news = USER_INT
lib.news {
    userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
    pluginName = Pi1
    vendorName = GeorgRinger
    extensionName = News
    controller = News
    settings < plugin.tx_news.settings
    settings {
          categories = 1
          #limit = 6
          detailPid = 6
          overrideFlexformSettingsIfEmpty := addToList(detailPid)
          startingpoint = 21
          hidePagination = 0
          categoryConjunction = or
    }
    persistence =< plugin.tx_news.persistence
    view =< plugin.tx_news.view
}

[(request.getQueryParams()['tx_news_pi1'])['news'] > 0 || (request.getParsedBody()['tx_news_pi1'])['news'] > 0]
    lib.newslist = COA
    lib.newslist {
        10 < lib.news
        10 {
            action = detail
            switchableControllerActions.News.1 = detail
            stdWrap.wrap = <section class="blog-section"><div class="container">|</div></section>
        }
        20 = RECORDS
        20 {
            source = 307
            dontCheckPid = 1
            tables = tt_content
        } 
    }
[else]
    lib.newslist < lib.news
    lib.newslist {
        action = list
        switchableControllerActions.News.1 = list
        stdWrap.wrap = <div class="section-heading mb-5"><h2>Blog</h2></div>|
    }
[end]

[else]
    lib.newslist = COA
    lib.newslist {
        action = list
        switchableControllerActions.News.1 = list
        stdWrap.wrap = <div class="section-heading mb-5"><h2>Blog</h2></div>|
    }
[end]
```

Now I needs to add a category list to this. So I have added the following TypoScript:

```html
lib.categoryMenu = USER
lib.categoryMenu {
        userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
        extensionName = News
        pluginName = Pi1
        vendorName = GeorgRinger

        action = category
        switchableControllerActions {
                Category {
                        1 = list
                }
        }
           
        settings < plugin.tx_news.settings
        settings {
                listPid = 6
        }
}
```

The problem in this is there is no list page or detail page, so what will I give instead of the `listPid = 6` (6 is the page from which I called the TypoScript objects).

And please suggest if there is any other method to implement this category selection without specifying the list page.

Comment: I don't understand why listPid is used here. But your cObject is called from a page. So why not setting the listPid dynamically to the UID of the calling page?

Comment: 6 is the PID of that calling page. It will lead to an error because there is no configuration for the categories